# Get top results for each group (in Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

How would I be able to get N results for several groups in
an oracle query.

For example, given the following table:

```
|--------+------------+------------|
| emp_id | name       | occupation |
|--------+------------+------------|
|      1 | John Smith | Accountant |
|      2 | Jane Doe   | Engineer   |
|      3 | Jack Black | Funnyman   |
|--------+------------+------------|
```

There are many more rows with more occupations.  I would like to get
three employees (lets say) from each occupation.

Is there a way to do this without using a subquery?

Comment: This is **NOT** a duplicate of [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column) - that question is looking for a single-row-per-group and the majority of the solutions are not applicable to this question which is asking for multiple-rows-per-group.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This produces what you want, and it uses no vendor-specific SQL features like TOP N or RANK().

```
SELECT MAX(e.name) AS name, MAX(e.occupation) AS occupation 
FROM emp e 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN emp e2 
    ON (e.occupation = e2.occupation AND e.emp_id <= e2.emp_id) 
GROUP BY e.emp_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3 
ORDER BY occupation;
```

In this example it gives the three employees with the lowest emp_id values per occupation.  You can change the attribute used in the inequality comparison, to make it give the top employees by name, or whatever.

Comment: @codemon2002, use the answer posted by jop on this thread. In Oracle, you can use windowing functions, which are intended for this kind of query.

Answer (score 42):

I don't have an oracle instance handy right now so I have not tested this:

```
select *
from (select emp_id, name, occupation,
      rank() over ( partition by occupation order by emp_id) rank
      from employee)
where rank <= 3
```

Here is a link on how rank works: http://www.psoug.org/reference/rank.html

Comment: Didnt he specify without a subquery...?

Comment: Yes, but he may well have meant "without using a subquery that selects from the same table again".  This solution uses a subquery but only accesses the table once.

Comment: Works great, seems to be lean on the DB as well.

Answer (score 3):

Add RowNum to rank :

```
select * from 
         (select emp_id, name, occupation,rank() over ( partition by occupation order by emp_id,RowNum) rank   
                      from employee) 
         where rank <= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is very efficient, but maybe a starting place?

```
select *
from people p1
    join people p2
        on p1.occupation = p2.occupation
    join people p3
        on p1.occupation = p3.occupation
        and p2.occupation = p3.occupation
where p1.emp_id != p2.emp_id
    and p1.emp_id != p3.emp_id
```

This should give you rows that contain 3 distinct employees all in the same occupation.  Unfortunately, it will give you ALL combinations of those.

Can anyone pare this down please?

Answer (score 1):

tested this in SQL Server (and it uses subquery)

```
select emp_id, name, occupation
from employees t1
where emp_id IN (select top 3 emp_id from employees t2 where t2.occupation = t1.occupation)
```

just do an ORDER by in the subquery to suit your needs