# Get top N records grouped by another field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle table with ID, SUBJECT, and PAYLOAD (CLOB). I'd like to get a listing of the TOP 10 records who have the biggest PAYLOAD (LENGTH(PAYLOAD)) grouped by subject. So if I have 10 DISTINCT SUBJECT's in the table, the query should return 100 rows (top 10 per subject).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134958/get-top-results-for-each-group-in-oracle

Comment: I saw that but it doesn't quite work. Need something that evaluates LENGTH of the field, not just an ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by subject order by length(payload) desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 10;
```